# using the same instance of SQLCommand more than one time in the same code for more than one query?

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

I have question about using why i can not use the same instance of SQLCommand more than one time in the same code?

I tried the code down here and it runs good for the gridview but when i changed the query  by using `cmd.CommandText()` method it keeps saying:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

This is the code:

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select top 10 FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State from Customers";

    GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
    GridView1.DataBind();


    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 10 COUNT(CreditLimit) FROM Customers";
    int total = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    TotalCreditLble.Text = "The total Credit :" + total.ToString();

}
catch(Exception exp)
{
    Response.Write(exp.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using the `SqlCommand` object to generate a DataReader via the `command.ExecuteReader()` command. While that is open, you can't re-use the command.

This should work:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    GridView1.DataSource = reader;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
//now the DataReader is closed/disposed and can re-use command
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 10 COUNT(CreditLimit) FROM Customers";
int total = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
TotalCreditLble.Text = "The total Credit :" + total.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

This is the very reason you don't share a command. Somewhere in your code you did this:

```
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

but you didn't leverage the `using` statement around the command because you wanted to share it. You can't do that. See, `ExecuteReader` leaves a connection to the server open while you read one row at a time; however that command is locked now because it's stateful at this point. The proper approach, **always**, is this:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c))
    {
        // inside of here you can use ExecuteReader
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // use the reader
        }
    }
}
```

These are *unmanaged resources* and need to be handled with care. That's why wrapping them with the `using` is imperative.

**Do not share these objects.** Build them, open them, use them, and dispose them.

By leveraging the `using` you will *never have to worry* about getting these objects closed and disposed.

---

Your code, written a little differently:

```
var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString;
var gridSql = "Select top 10 FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State from Customers";
var cntSql = "SELECT TOP 10 COUNT(CreditLimit) FROM Customers";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    con.Open();

    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(gridSql, con))
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cntSql, con))
        {
            int total = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            TotalCreditLble.Text = "The total Credit :" + total.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        Response.Write(exp.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your sentiment about not re-using commands/connections as it can only get you in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Thank u quys but for the guys who where talking about using block !
why this code work fine which i seen it on example on a video ! It's the same thing using the same instance of SqlCommand and passing diffrent queries by using the method CommanText with the same instance of SqlCommand and it's execute just fine , this is the code :

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.Connection = con;
   con.Open();

   cmd.CommandText = "Delete from tbleProduct where ProductID= 4";
   int TotalRowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   Response.Write("Total rows affected :" + TotalRowsAffected );

   cmd.CommandText = "Insert into tbleProduct values (4, 'Calculator', 100, 230)";
   TotalRowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   Response.Write("Total rows affected :" + TotalRowsAffected );


   cmd.CommandText = "ypdate tbleProduct set QtyAvailbe = 234 where ProductID = 2";
   TotalRowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   Response.Write("Total rows affected :" + TotalRowsAffected );

 }
```